# How to clear textarea field onclick in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

How to clear `textarea` field onclick? the problem is I am using **AJAX**. it won't reload the page. can anyone help me to solve this problem.

```
<div class="write_comment" style="">
  <textarea type="text" id="form_task_comment" name="form_task_comment" value="" placeholder="Write your comment here..."></textarea>
  <div class="buttons" style="float:right">
        <button id="btn_comment_submit" class="btn btn-default btn hoverable btn-sm btn_comment_submit" style="margin:0rem;" type="submit">Add Comment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share you ajax and other relevant code as well.

Comment: Run `$('#form_task_comment').val('')` under whatever event you require

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Click on button to clear Textarea

```js
$('.clearText').click(function(){
  $("#form_task_comment").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clearText">Click Here To Clear Textarea</button>
<br>
<textarea id="form_task_comment">This is textarea</textarea>
```

Comment: @PrabhudevVatnal If it helped you then don't forgot to accept answer

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to use jQuery. And the other posts above do not mention how to reset your textarea ON send. When you bind onclick, it would clear the text BEFORE sending. Therefore you need to use form onsubmit

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById("form_task_comment")
var form = document.getElementById("form-name")
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  textArea.value = "";
  event.preventDefault();
}, false)
```

```html
<div class="write_comment" style="">
<form id="form-name" >
<textarea type="text" id="form_task_comment" name="form_task_comment" value="" placeholder="Write your comment here..."></textarea>
  <div class="buttons" style="float:right">
        <button id="btn_comment_submit" class="btn btn-default btn hoverable btn-sm btn_comment_submit" style="margin:0rem;" type="submit">Add Comment</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just replace textarea.value with nothing when button is clicked??

html code:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Text" onclick="eraseText();"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
function eraseText() 
{
   document.getElementById("form_task_comment").value = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply clear the value of text area using `.val()` like this

```js
$("#form_task_comment").val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="form_task_comment">This is textarea</textarea>
```

Add this line of code wherever you want to clear the text area